# RxJs Observable forkJoin

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm writing a service in Angular 5 (RxJs 5.5.1) and I have the following scenario where I'm trying to implement a login workflow.

```
...
signInBasic(user: string, pwd: string): Observable<AuthenticationStatus> {
    return this.http.post('some_url', params, { observe: 'response', responseType: 'text' })
      .map((response: HttpResponse<Object>) => {
        this.status = response.status === 200 ? AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated : AuthenticationStatus.NotAuthenticated;
        return this.status;
      })
      ...
      /* HERE */
      ...

}

getPrimaryInfo(): Observable<any> {}
getPermissions(): Observable<any> {}
...
```

At the `/* HERE */` point, depending on `this.status` value (`Authenticated` specifically) I would like to fire two more HTTP requests (via `getPrimaryInfo` and `getPermissions` methods) in order to get some user's details from the backend. After both complete, I would like to return `this.status` as returned value of `signInBasic` method. If the user is not authenticated, I will anyway return `this.status` with `AuthenticationStatus.NotAuthenticated` value since it was set before.

I was looking to `forkJoin` but I don't understand how I can return something only when those two HTTP calls complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `concatMap` to wait for `forkJoin` to complete and then map the result into `this.status` regardless of what the two requests returned.

```
signInBasic(user: string, pwd: string) {
  return this.http.post('some_url', params, ...)
    .concatMap((response: HttpResponse<Object>) => {
      this.status = response.status === 200 ? AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated : AuthenticationStatus.NotAuthenticated;

      if (this.status === AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated) {
        return forkJoin(getPrimaryInfo(), getPermissions())
          .pipe(
            map(() => this.status),
          );
      } else {
        return of(this.status);
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: This will send the value through twice, which is likely not the intended behavior. This is a case for switchMap with a projection function

Comment: Why would it send it twice?

Comment: because concatMap emits the source values and the inner values

Comment: No, it doesn't. It emits only value(s) from the inner Observable because it expects you to "map" values from the source Observable into another Observable.

Comment: my mistake, confused it with normal concat

Comment: Thank you, I have accepted your answer because I like it a bit more compared to the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

switchMap with a projection function is your friend in this case:

```
return this.http.post('some_url', params, { observe: 'response', responseType: 'text' })
  .map((response: HttpResponse<Object>) => {
    this.status = response.status === 200 ? AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated : AuthenticationStatus.NotAuthenticated;
    return this.status;
  })
  .switchMap(status => (status === AutheticationStatuses.Authenticated)
                          ? forkJoin(getPrimaryInfo(), getPermissions())
                          : of(null),
             (status, inner) => status);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, much appreciated.